# Update table by join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a exchange rate table like below

```
FromCurrency    ToCurrency          ValidFrom               ExchangeRate
USD             ZAR         2012-01-05 00:00:00.000         7.7260000000
USD             ZAR         2012-01-04 00:00:00.000         7.6740000000
USD             ZAR         2012-01-03 00:00:00.000         7.4601000000
USD             ZAR         2012-01-02 00:00:00.000         7.7600000000
USD             ZAR         2012-01-01 00:00:00.000         8.0945000000
EUR             NOK         2012-01-05 00:00:00.000         7.5881000000
EUR             NOK         2012-01-04 00:00:00.000         7.5974000000
EUR             NOK         2012-01-03 00:00:00.000         7.4494000000
EUR             NOK         2012-01-02 00:00:00.000         7.6606000000
EUR             NOK         2012-01-01 00:00:00.000         7.7740000000
USD             AED         2012-01-05 00:00:00.000         3.6731000000
USD             AED         2012-01-04 00:00:00.000         3.6731000000
```

My main table is

```
Transaction Date    Amount  Currency    FromCurrency
13971   5/27/2011    8000     USD   USD
13971   7/31/2011   -6809.4   ZAR   USD
13971   8/30/2011   -425.59   ZAR   USD
13971   9/27/2011   -6809.4   ZAR   USD
67467   11/8/2011    5000     GBP   GBP
67467   12/21/2011  -5195.06  ZAR   GBP
67467   1/30/2012   -5195.06  ZAR   GBP
81181   4/15/2011    6000     USD   USD
81181   6/28/2011   -5159.03  ZAR   USD
82418   10/21/2011   5000     EUR   EUR
82418   1/27/2012   -3919.97  NOK   EUR
```

Above is sample data of table, my actual table has millions of records. I have to multiply amount with exchange rate column (from exchange rate table) and update the corresponding FromCurrency (from exchange rate table) with currency column in my table.

I have tried many ways but couldn't find the solution. The tricky part here is there is not matching date for my table in exchange rate table.

Exchange rate should be applied like this. If my transaction date is Feb-20-2012 and Currency is ZAR and FromCurrency is USD then I have to pick the below row from exchange rate table

```
USD             ZAR         2012-01-02 00:00:00.000         7.7600000000
```

Comment: what would be your output table can u show me?

Comment: @AnandPhadke myoutput table is same as my main table. I have to update amount and currecy column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update transactions
set FromCurrencyAmount = transactions.amount * 
    (select top 1 exchangerate from exchangerates where validfrom <= transactions.date 
       and transactions.fromcurrency = exchangerates.fromcurrency
       and transactions.currency = exchangerates.tocurrency
       order by validfrom desc)
```

To select

```
select transactions.*, 
    (select top 1 exchangerate from exchangerates where validfrom <= transactions.date 
       and transactions.fromcurrency = exchangerates.fromcurrency
       and transactions.currency = exchangerates.tocurrency
       order by validfrom desc) 
from transactions
```

Comment: Can you please give the select version of this query. I want to select the exchange rates and see before actually updating my main table. Many thank for the answer.

Comment: @poduluska Thanks a lot, really I couldn’t convert that statement to select statement. so much to learn in SQL !

Comment: @poduluska I noticed that this query is getting me top exchange rate form the the selected bucket. For USD to ZAR, If I have 1-Mar-2012, 1-May-2012, 1-Jun-2012 exchange rates. Query is getting me 1-Jun-2012 exchange rate even if my transaction date is 1-Apr-2012.

Comment: It should get 1-Mar-2012 exchange rate for 11-Apr-2012 transaction and 1-May-2012 exchange rate for 21-May-2012 transaction. But this query is getting only 1-Jun-2012 exchange rate(top in the bucket) exchange rate for both the transactions.

Comment: @Nani You are either storing your dates oddly, or you have mistransposed the query.

Comment: @podiluska thats true, I think I have problem with dates. let me rebuild tables and test. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Query worked fine, problem was with my date columns.

I just reviewed this query with my lead. I have one last request for you. 

Here every transaction is multiplied by corresponding exchange rate but we should multiply only first transaction exchange rate with all its consecutive transactions till we see a change in currency.

That is, if an advance is taken (positive amount) than corresponding recoveries(negative amounts) should be multiplied only with the first recovery transaction exchange rate.

Comment: @podiluska I am really troubling you in weekend. I taught today I will complete this early but no luck. Full day went in this. It took half day for me to construct FromCurrency column in  main table :(

Comment: @podiluska I think I can acomplish this with same query appling again. This time on the main table to get exchange rate of minmum transaction date.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is :

```
select * from
transact t1 join exchRate e1 on t1.FromCurrency = e1.FromCurrency 
and t1.ToCurrency = e1.ToCurrency
and t1.tdate > e1.ValidFrom 
and not exists 
(select 1 from exchRate where ValidFrom < t1.tdate and ValidFrom > e1.ValidFrom)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am having same problem as I mentioned below with this approch too. For USD to ZAR, If I have 1-Mar-2012, 1-May-2012, 1-Jun-2012 exchange rates. Query is getting me 1-Jun-2012 exchange rate even if my transaction date is 11-Apr-2012 or 21-May-2012. 

It should get 1-Mar-2012 exchange rate for 11-Apr-2012 transaction and 1-May-2012 exchange rate for 21-May-2012 transaction.

Comment: I think you are confused with date format (e.g 01/03/2012 may be 1-Mar-2012 or 3-Jan-2012 )

Comment: you are absolutely correct. Exchange rate table date was in UK format and my main table date column is in us format. sorry, I rectifed the mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand

```
 SELECT T3.*,
   T4.DATEMAX,
   T4.VALUESELECTED
   FROM   TRANSACTIONS AS T3
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT T.CURRENCY,
           T.FROMCURRENCY,
           T.DATEMAX,
           T2.EXCHANGERATE AS VALUESELECTED
    FROM   (SELECT   CURRENCY,
                     FROMCURRENCY,
                     MAX(ValidFrom) AS DATEMAX
            FROM     ExChangeRate
            WHERE    ValidFrom <= T3.DATE
            GROUP BY Currency, FromCurrency) AS T
           INNER JOIN
           ExChangeRate AS T2
           ON T.CURRENCY = T2.CURRENCY
              AND T.FROMCURRENCY = T2.FROMCURRENCY
              AND T.DATEMAX = T2.VALIDFROM) AS T4
   ON T4.CURRENCY = T3.CURRENCY
      AND T4.FROMCURRENCY = T3.FROMCURRENCY;
```